# Kafka pod in Kubernetes has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I am using Kubernetes for my project and I was using Helm to install Jaeger and Kafka in a simple way. The problem is that regarding kafka, the zookeeper pods started correctly I have one pod that is "Pending" since the beginning.

I used this command `kubectl --namespace=default describe pod my-kafka-kafka-0` and got this information:

**`Warning  FailedScheduling  55m (x398 over 2h)   default-scheduler  pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)`**

I have no idea how to solve this issue since I am new to Kubernetes and i thought that using Helm, deploying apps with it would be straightforward.

I am sorry if my question is not done in the correct way but it is also my first time here :)

Thank you in advance for your time and I would be really happy if someone could help me!

Comment: Could you explain which provider are you using for store Kubernetes?

Comment: The problem is that your Kubernetes cluster is not capable of creating the persistent volumes needed by Kafka